# Unable to pull image from the Gitlab container registry

Tags: docker, gitlab

I have created some images in the Gitlab Container Registry. I am unable to pull them using docker on my local system. The login command succeeds but when I type the following command:

```
docker pull reg-gitlab-project.company.com/services/palimited/integrationservices/springbootproject/springbootproject:latest
```

I am getting the following error

```
Error response from daemon: Head "https://reg-gitlab-project.company.com/v2/services/palimited/integrationservices/springbootproject/springbootproject/manifests/latest": denied: access forbidden
```

I am unable to figure out why this error is occuring? Can anyone guide me.

Answer (score 2):

You need to authenticate with the container registry at `reg-gitlab-project.company.com` before issuing a `docker pull` command.

See, [GitLab Docs: Authenticate with the Container Registry](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/container_registry/authenticate_with_container_registry.html).

Comment: Link moved here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/container_registry/authenticate_with_container_registry.html